# DocuSign Integrator Key permissions

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any way to limit the access of an integrator key to a specific security group in DocuSign? For instance I only want to be able to get envelopes created by users who are part of a specific group. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Impose limits on your app by making the individual users log into it. Eg use [Authorization Code Grant](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html) flow so an individual user will log into the app and then the app will have the individual user's permissions capability.

You should only create a "[service integration](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html)" if there is no way for a user to log in.

The integration key enables your app to use the api. The integration key does not grant any privileges *per se*. Privileges are granted by the login used.